# overlay SVG on leaflet latLngBounds

Tags: javascript, svg, plotly, leaflet

I am using Plotly to generate an SVG contour plot. Subsequently, I aim to overlay this SVG contour onto a map with specific boundaries. My intention is to resize the SVG to fit these boundaries, similar to overlaying an image. However, despite the SVG being contained within the specified bounds, the contour lines do not cover the entire SVG and there is a blank space on the right side of the SVG[image].

```
var levels = {
            start: 0.2,
            end: 0.5,
            size: 0.01,
          }; 

          var contourTrace = {
            z: data,
            type: "contour",
            contours: {
              start: levels.start,
              end: levels.end,
              size: levels.size,
              showlabels: true, 
            },
          };

          var layout = {
            margin: { t: 0, r: 0, b: 0, l: 0 }, 
            xaxis: { visible: false },
            yaxis: { visible: false },
          };

          Plotly.newPlot("map1", [contourTrace], layout).then(function () {
            var svgContent = document.querySelector("#map1 svg");
            if (svgContent) {
              var width = svgContent.getAttribute("width");
              var height = svgContent.getAttribute("height");
              

              console.log(width, height);

              svgContent.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
              svgContent.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + width + " " + height);
            }

            var svgOverlay = L.svgOverlay(svgContent, latLngBounds, {
              opacity: 0.9,
              interactive: true,
            }).addTo(map);

            
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because of how Plotly creates SVGs. I have to compute the contour width instead of the SVG width.

```js
var trueWidth = document
  .querySelector("#map1 svg .cartesianlayer")
  .getBoundingClientRect().width;
var height = svgContent.getAttribute("height");
svgContent.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "none");
svgContent.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + trueWidth + " " + height);
```